# Azure AD Authentication from WinForm app in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I developed VSTO Excel Add-In application(desktop) and I need now to authenticate against Azure Active Directory. I use MSAL.NET and I achieve that by eventually calling:

```
     //System.Windows.Window win = (System.Windows.Window)ThisAddIn.ExcelActiveWindow;
     //IntPtr parentInteropHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(win).Handle;
     Log.Verbose("calling AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token...");
     authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                            .WithAccount(firstAccount)
                            //.WithParentActivityOrWindow(parentInteropHandle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                            .ExecuteAsync();
```

In general, it works. As the result I get a web browser page popup to enter username, which I provide and then another web browser popup asking for password, etc...

However, one of the problems I have is that the web browser popup is ugly: it takes 1/3 of the screen in width and full height. It is also non-resizable. It looks that MSAL.NET launches another executable to that...
Now, back to the commented line in code: I had impression that if I provide a window from my app it will be used as a parent and the browser will fit into it - that was mislead hope - the browser window is even bigger in that case where I provide a small window of type System.Windows.Window. And when I provide Excel Main Window it crashes on the first commented line.
So now, I am thinking maybe I will popup a small custom dialog in Excel and call it from there?
Any thoughts, examples, on how I can present smaller popup browser window?